# Determine the value of base x if $(211)_x=(152)_8$

Tags: computer-science, quadratics

$(211)_x=(152)_8$

I did:

$$2*x^2+x^1+1 = 1*8^2+5*8+2 \Leftrightarrow \\
2x^2+x-104 = 0$$

Only this gives me 2 non integer roots. What did I do wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: It's $105$, not $104$.

Comment: Using $2 x^2 + x - 105$ as equation, we find $7$ as a root. One can quickly confirm that this gives a right answer.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Well that was silly. Thanks, got it